# cakePHP 3.0.7 - Unable to call method "" in "default" provider for field "member_selected"

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In MembersTable.php I have:

```
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('member_selected')
        ->add('member_selected', ['rule' => ['inList', [0,1], false]]);

    return $validator;
```

I am receiving the following very cryptic message from cakePHP 3.0.7

```
Unable to call method "" in "default" provider for field member_selected" InvalidArgumentException

⟩ Cake\Validation\ValidationRule->process CORE\src\Validation\Validator.php, line 656
⟩ Cake\Validation\Validator->_processRules CORE\src\Validation\Validator.php, line 136
⟩ Cake\Validation\Validator->errors CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 181
⟩ Cake\ORM\Marshaller->_validate CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 428
⟩ Cake\ORM\Marshaller->merge CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 2034
⟩ Cake\ORM\Table->patchEntity APP/Controller\MembersController.php, line 104
⟩ App\Controller\MembersController->edit [internal function]
⟩ call_user_func_array CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 411
⟩ Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 114
⟩ Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 87
⟩ Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 37
```

If I remove the ->add('member_selected', ['rule' => ['inList' ...
every thing works ok, but of course the validation is not being done correctly.  I do not have an example of the use if 'inList' but I think I've got it setup correctly.  I have several other fields of this table that I've had to remove other validator rules from to get past this error message (e.g. naturalNumber).

I also will reference another stackoverflow question titled "cakePHP 3.0.7 - Baked edit function fails to perform save in patchEntity with Marshaller::merge() error."

The problems can be "resolved" by altering the $validator setting for one of the fields...  One of ways to create these errors is to change field name or type, and forget to change it in Entity $_accessible, and Table $validator inside function validationDefault().  Also don't forget $rules->adds in Table::buildRules()

Of course... why would anyone want to change a field name or type?  Oh well, it would be nice if cakePHP would give some information as to the actual problem (expected field does not exist, or field specified should not exist).

Anyway, now that I've blown off a little steam, the validator is not reporting anything useful when it blows up.  I hope someone is watching stackoverflow so it can be resolved.

Having said all this, I'm still wondering why the 'inList' rule does NOT work?

**Answer to why inList, and naturalNumber did not work for me!**

```
 add public

add( string $field , array|string $name , array|Cake\Validation\ValidationRule $rule [] )

Adds a new rule to a field's rule set. If second argument is an array then rules list for the field will be replaced with second argument and third argument will be ignored.
Example:

$validator
->add('title', 'required', ['rule' => 'notBlank'])
->add('user_id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric', 'message' => 'Invalid User'])

$validator->add('password', [
'size' => ['rule' => ['lengthBetween', 8, 20]],
'hasSpecialCharacter' => ['rule' => 'validateSpecialchar', 'message' => 'not valid']
]);
```

**Well, it's not true!  You cannot leave out the second argument!**  All errors during validation (which are incorrectly reported as far as I'm concerned) go away if I always specify the second arg and then the 3rd arg specifies the rules!

Thanks to everyone who may read and offer assistance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give your rule a 'name' of your own liking

```
->add('member_selected', 'rule_name', ['rule' => ['inList', [0,1], false]]);
```

Comment: I have added rule_name also, but still getting this error, I have created custom validator. Any idea?